# collatz conjecture, finding max number in sequence

Tags: c

hey guys i have to write a function
that returns the max number in the collatz sequence(not the length),
for example
if n==7
the output should be 52 because its the largest number ;

```
int collatz_max(int n)
{
    int max=0;
        if(collatz_max(n)>max)
            {
           max=n;
            return max;
            }
        if(n%2==0)
        {
          return   collatz_max(n=n/2);
        }
        else
        
           return  collatz_max(n=n*3+1);
        }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like an obvious problem in which to use recursion. Why not run through the collatz sequence keeping track of the maximum number found so far, and return it once the sequence terminates (assuming it does).

Comment: I'm not sure which version of the C standard you've read, but `collatz_max(n=n*3+1)` looks like you're trying to use a keyword argument -- a feature that C does not possess. What this expression actually does, it assign `n*3+1` to `n`, and then call `collatz_max` with the result of this assignment.

Comment: yes its my fault
even though it still does not work

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
  if(collatz_max(n)>max)
```

Is just calling itself without changing `n` or doing anything else. So it would repeatedly just keep calling itself until it runs out of stack. You need to rethink the algorithm

Comment: i really tried so many things but none has worked :(